# groovy inject map with other map

Tags: groovy, inject

```
    Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> Actions =  new HashMap<Integer, Map<String, String>>();
    Map<Integer, List<ActionName>> actionList = Service.getAvailableActionsById(order.id, user.id)

    for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<ActionName>> entry : actionList)
    {
      Map<String, String> actionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
      for(ActionName actionName: entry.getValue()){
        actionMap.put(actionName.name(), actionName.name());
      }
      Actions.put(entry.getKey(), actionMap);
    }
```

--==//   For the same functionality above I want to use map inject, while doing as below it unable to inject all the list values to map

```
 Map<Integer, List<ActionName>> actionList = [:]
    if ( order.id) actionList = Service.getAvailableActionsById(order.id, session.user.id)

    Map Actions = actionList.inject( [:] ) { map, id, values -> map.put( id, values ); return map;  }
```

--=====

Comment: Apparently, you are trying to create another similar map from the original map but the definition is different for both the maps. The source map is `Map<Integer, List<OtherClaimLIActionName>>` and the target map is `Map<Integer, Map<String, String>>`. What you are trying to do in inject is totally different. What are you trying to achieve in `availableOtherClaimLIActions` map?

Comment: If you see above code with for loop, which is processed with entry. Their for each key we will have a actionMap. In short I can say same result as for loop, but through inject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map availableActions = actionList.inject( [:] ) { map, key, listValue -> 
    map << [ (key) : listValue.collectEntries { [ it.name(), it.name() ] } ]
}
```

This should give what you are looking for, but I do not get the rationale behind doing this.

Comment: I have even tried similar to this, but that inserted null object.

Comment: map << [ (key): listValue.collectEntries { [ it.name(), it.name() ]} ] worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

`inject`'s closure takes to arguments: result and current element. If you want to call `inject()` on a map you should treat each element as a `Map.Entry`:

```
actionList.inject( [:] ) { map, elem -> 
  map[ elem.key ] = elem.value // key -> id, value -> values 
  map
}
```

Comment: But it is not adding all values in list. I mean this also work similar as my code for injection.

Comment: @injecteer You can have inject with 3 args in case of a map. `init, key, value ->`

Comment: @dmahapatro: ? the method call takes an init and a closure. the closure only takes 2 args.

Comment: I meant the closure can take 3 args in case of a map. The init value , the key and the value. @NathanHughes . Here `actionList` is a map, if you look closely. :) Let me rectify my previous comment.

Comment: @injecteer You can have inject with 3 args closure in case of a map. `init, key, value ->`